# Flutter web paste image from clipboard to <List>Uint8List

Tags: flutter, image, clipboard

My flutter web feature right now can be able to select files from disk to Uint8List. With  Uint8List I can display selected images by widget.
Now I am adding more feature to the web. My motivation is Twitter copy/paste image and post. 
The following is my attempt to read image from memory, but it return `null` to me.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pasteboard/pasteboard.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Experiment extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/experiment';
  const Experiment({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Experiment> createState() => _ExperimentState();
}

class _ExperimentState extends State<Experiment> {
  List<Uint8List>? _pickedBytes = <Uint8List>[];

  void clickPaste() async {
    var bytes = await Pasteboard.image;
    print("xx");
    print(bytes);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text("Experiment"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: clickPaste,
              child: Text("BTN"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Question:**
How to let flutter web read the image from clipboard to `<List>Uint8List`?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32045

Answer (score 0):

The working example is here. But it support only `Text`.

```dart
/// Data stored on the system clipboard.
///
/// The system clipboard can contain data of various media types. This data
/// structure currently supports only plain text data, in the [text] property.
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Experiment extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/experiment';
  const Experiment({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Experiment> createState() => _ExperimentState();
}

class _ExperimentState extends State<Experiment> {
  Future<void> _clipboardToWidget() async {
    var data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
    print(data?.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text("Experiment"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _clipboardToWidget,
              child: Text("BBTN"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```